# How to get rid of FULL TABLE SCAN in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance

I have one query and it is giving me full table scan while doing explain plan , so will you tell me how to get rid of it.

output:

```
|*  9 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | GL_PERIODS_U1        |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL          | GL_PERIODS           |    12 |   372 |       |     6   (0)|
|* 11 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | GL_JE_HEADERS        |     1 |    37 |       |   670   (0)|
|* 12 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | GL_JE_HEADERS_N2     |  3096 |       |       |    11   (0)|
|* 13 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | GL_JE_BATCHES        |     1 |     8 |       |     2   (0)|
|* 14 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | GL_JE_BATCHES_U1     |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|
|* 15 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | GL_JE_LINES_U1       |   746 |       |       |     4   (0)|
|  16 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL               | GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS |  1851K|    30M|       | 13023   (1)|
```

My query :

```
explain plan for 
    select cc.segment1,
           cc.segment2,
           h.currency_code,
           SUM(NVL(l.accounted_dr,0) - NVL(l.accounted_cr,0))
    from   gl_code_combinations cc
          ,gl_je_lines   l
          ,gl_je_headers h
          ,gl_je_batches b
          ,gl_periods    p1  
          ,gl_periods    p2  
    where   cc.code_combination_id = l.code_combination_id
    AND     b.je_batch_id = h.je_batch_id
    AND     b.status = 'P'
    AND     l.je_header_id = h.je_header_id
    AND     h.je_category = 'Revaluation'
    AND     h.period_name     = p1.period_name
    AND    p1.period_set_name = 'Equant Master'
    AND    p2.period_name = 'SEP-16'
    AND    p2.period_set_name = 'Equant Master'
    AND    p1.start_date     <= p2.end_date
    AND    h.set_of_books_id = '1429'
    GROUP BY cc.segment1,
            cc.segment2,
            h.currency_code
```

please suggest

Comment: Table full scan it's not bad at all. Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Regarding the FTS on `GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS`, can you post the entire explain plan, including headers?  You are specifying the PK for that table in a join, but it is possible that you have to look up -- or Oracle thinks you will have to look up -- a significant percentage of the rows.  A `CARDINALITY` or a `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hint might help.

Comment: Here are the full explain plan:

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the Oracle e-Business Suite data model.  In that model, `GL_PERIODS`, being the table of accounting periods (usually weeks or months), is usually fairly small.  Further, you are telling it you want every period *prior* to September 2016, which is likely to be almost all the periods in your "Equant Master" period set.  Depending on how many other period sets you have defined, your full table scan may very well be the optimal (fastest running) plan.

As others have correctly pointed out, full table scans aren't necessarily worse or slower than other access paths.

To determine if your FTS really is a problem, you can use `DBMS_XPLAN` to get timings of how long each step in your plan is taking.  Like this:

#### First, tell Oracle to keep track of plan-step-level statistics for your session

```
alter session set statistics_level = ALL;
```

#### Make sure you turn of DBMS_OUTPUT / server output

#### Run your query to completion (i.e., scroll to the bottom of the result set)

#### Finally, run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor (null, null,
                                         'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

The output will tell you *exactly* why your query is taking so long (if it *is* taking long).  It is much more accurate than just picking out all the full table scans in your explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, why do you want to avoid full table scan? All full table scans are not bad.

You are joining on the same table cc.code_combination_id = l.code_combination_id. I don't think there is a away to avoid full table scan on these type of joins.

To understand this, I created test tables and data.

create table I1(n number primary key, v varchar2(10)); 
create table I2(n number primary key, v varchar2(10));

and a map table 
create table MAP(n number primary key, i1 number referencing I1(n), 
i2 number referencing I2(n));

I created index on map table.
create index map_index_i1 on map(i1);
create index map_index_i2 on map(i2);

Here is the sample data that I inserted.

SQL> select * from i1;

```
     N V
```

---

```
     1 ONE
     2 TWO
     5 FIVE
```

SQL> select * from i2;

```
     N V
```

---

```
     3 THREE
     4 FOUR
     5 FIVE
```

SQL> select * from map;

```
     N         I1         I2
```

---

```
     1          1          3
     2          1          4
     5          5          5
```

I do gathered the statistics. Then, I executed the query which uses I1 and I2 from map table.

```
explain plan for
select map.n,i1.v 
from i1,map
where map.i2 = map.i1
and i1.n=5
```

Remember, we have index on I1 and I2 of map table. I thought the optimizer might use the index, but unfortunately it didn't.

[Full table scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SWIe.png)

Because the condition map.i2 = map.i1 means compare every record of map table's I2 column with I1.

Next, I used one of the indexed columns in the where condition and now it picked the index.

```
explain plan for
select map.n,i1.v
from i1,map
where map.i2 = map.i1
and i1.n=5
and map.i1=5
```

[Index scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLTgN.png)

Have a look at ASK Tom's pages for full table scans. Unfortunately, I couldn't paste the source an link since I have less than 10 reputation !!

Comment: Is my records in GL_JE_LINES tables will also creating some problem ....as there are millions records present in table for specific entity ans takes time